# Outlook is removing message prefixes on listserv messages, how to make it NOT do this?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We are using Mailman3 to provide lists for some users.  Unfortunately, we have a small problem.

When the email is sent from the List, it gets a prefix, a-la `[List-0000003]` appended based on the subject/discussion thread ID that's specified.  So a subject might be `[List-0000003] Discussion Topic` on the email.

It seems Outlook doesn't like this nor wants to include this, and when we hit Reply or Reply All on any Outlook client, the client **strips** the subject line down to `Re: Discussion Topic` and *ignores* the prefix that was on the original subject line.

No other mail clients I"ve tested - Thunderbird included - do this.

Is there a way to find and **DISABLE** this functionality in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in custom forms feature within Outlook.

Create a custom form based on an IPM.Note form by selecting the Design Form option in the Tools menu in Outlook. Then publish the form to the personal folder in the list,

Modify the registry to tell Outlook to use a custom form to display emails instead of the default form.

See: [How do I fix Outlook's reply and forward subject prefixes?](https://superuser.com/questions/86337/how-do-i-fix-outlooks-reply-and-forward-subject-prefixes)